# eigenvalues and eigenvectors in R

Tags: r

When I have tried to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the following matrix using eigen() function, contrary my expectations, the smallest eigenvalue is not zero, why?

```
 > lapMatrix
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]  0.6 -0.1 -0.5  0.0
 [2,] -0.1  1.0  0.0 -0.9
 [3,] -0.5  0.0  1.0 -0.5
 [4,]  0.0 -0.9 -0.5  1.4

 > eigen(lapMatrix)
  $values
 [1] 2.277671e+00 1.241300e+00 4.810288e-01 1.297990e-16

 $vectors
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3] [,4]
 [1,]  0.1359786  0.5205445  0.6786333  0.5
 [2,] -0.5412623  0.3853145 -0.5554889  0.5
 [3,] -0.3480021 -0.7447136  0.2725734  0.5
 [4,]  0.7532858 -0.1611455 -0.3957179  0.5
```

Comment: `1.297990e-16` is quite close to zero.

Comment: but it is not exactly zero! is there any function to give me zero eigenvalue for this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply **round** the result:

```
round(eigen(mm)$values,2)
## [1] 2.28 1.24 0.48 0.00
```

You can wrap this within a small function :

```
reigen <- 
  function(...,digits =2) round(eigen(...)$values,digits)
```

Or using `zapsmall` like suggested in the comment ( it will determine automatically the number of digits):

```
reigen <- 
  function(...,digits =2) zapsmall(eigen(...)$values)

reigen(mm)
[1] 2.278 1.241 0.481 0.000
```

Comment: @MamounBenghezal thank you for your suggestion. I added it in my answer.

Comment: is this needed to do any correction on eigenvectors? Could you please give a code which computes eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix with the same order?

Comment: @Zaynab what do you mean by the same order here? Is that , the same number of digits precision? Here I am not affecting computation, just I format the output. You can do the same thing for eigen vectors also.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, is the column i of vectors element in the output of eigen function corresponds to the element i-th in the values element of the eigen output?

Comment: @Zaynab yes of course. Very easy to check ( this is not in relation to your original question), `r <- eigen(A); V <- r$vectors; lam <- r$values` Then you check for example : `V[,1] %*%t(A) equal to lam[1]*V[,1]`

Comment: The original question has arisen for me after checking this relation between the 4th eigenvalue and eigenvector, and I guessed that the output of eigen function may be incorrect because the smallest eigenvalue was not exactly zero. currently everything is ok and thank you for your help.